# How to make a button in this image

Tags: android, button, styles

I'm impressed with the button in this pic. Anybody can give me a keyword about this button to research in android? Thanks and best regards.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYT4K.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is a Floating Action Button.  Lots of detail at https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching floating action button android.(**Yours is Edit action button.**)

There are lot of action button in android introduced in material design -

1. Edit
2. Call
3. Add
   and many more

you can try below material design link for your edit action button.

[material action buttons](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/)

Answer (score 0):

The button you are looking is a combination of two widgets. The Bottom App Bar and Floating Action Button. To make this happen you have to apply a **gravity bottom** on bottom app bar and then apply **app:layout_anchor=@id/bottom_bar** on Floating Action Button. The root view should be **CoordinatorLayout**.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

In android, there is a widget called Floating Action Button.how to write given below

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart"
        android:contentDescription="Add"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textTv"/>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_open_in_new_white_24dp"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This will be your output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:fabAttached="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="12dp">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_alignment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Toggle FAB alignment"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Some notes to takeaway:**

Don’t call setSupportActionBar() with your provided BottomAppBar as it will break it

To change the background colour you should call app:backgroundTint instead of setBackground because of internal management of background

Calling setTitle or setSubtitle will have no effect as these methods are overriden and empty